# Failed to create global_planner/GlobalPlanner

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, ros-kinetic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have this error when trying to create a custom global planner.

`[FATAL] [1577962056.484219920, 8.805000000]: Failed to create the test_planner/GlobalPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type test_planner::GlobalPlanner as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()`

I've followed the custom tutorial on the ros wiki exactly, and rospack outputs as expected. I'm running move_base in a custom environment, which runs fine with the normal move_base parameters, and with the carrot_planner and global_planner plugins.

`<param name="base_global_planner" value="test_planner/GlobalPlanner"/>` and other planner plugins - [A star plugin](https://github.com/daggarwa/AStar_Plugin_ROS) and [Relaxed a star](https://github.com/coins-lab/relaxed_astar) - I've tried have all outputted the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve the error?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340900/failed-to-create-global_planner/globalplanner/) by [nocturnealley](https://answers.ros.org/users/50621/nocturnealley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-01-02**:
Please link to the tutorial you are following.

**Comment by [nocturnealley](https://answers.ros.org/users/50621/nocturnealley/) on 2020-01-02**:
[This](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) is the tutorial that I followed. I tried with the param value "global_planner/GlobalPlanner" as in the tutorial (PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS arguments and plugin description files were changed) but both versions don't work.

**Comment by [nocturnealley](https://answers.ros.org/users/50621/nocturnealley/) on 2020-01-05**:
Yup, I am. Thanks for your help. I restarted the computer and the error is gone. Not too sure why that is but the planner is working as expected now.

**Comment by [cgm666](https://answers.ros.org/users/71636/cgm666/) on 2021-03-08**:
Hi, have you solved this problem? I also meet it:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you launching on the same machine with the new package you've created on the path in the window you're launching in? I've found a simple `source ~/.bashrc` before you launch move_base sometimes solves problems.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0